# Is it possible to override the vb.net Resource Manager GetString function?

Tags: vb.net

In the auto-generated resource designer file, there are properties for each resource. The property calls "GetString" which returns the string value. I would like to override this getstring function so I can do logic to see if I need to retrieve this value or a different value. I can't figure out how to do this because the designer file is auto-generated.

```
Public ReadOnly Property General() As String
   Get
   Return ResourceManager.GetString("General", resourceCulture)
  End Get
End Property
```

For example, in my version of the GetString function, I would check the key passed in ("General") and see if there is a custom value for this key in a database. If the custom value exists, I would use that value. If the custom value does not exist, I would call the base GetString function to get the Resource value. I'd like to use the built in Resource class for this because then in my code I can just use "@Resources.General" and take advantage of the auto-complete functionality that already exists.

Comment: What do you mean by `this value or a different value`? Please expand on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [ASP.NET Resourcemanager to read local .resx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405877/asp-net-resourcemanager-to-read-local-resx). It's in C# but you can just convert it over. It isn't 100% of what you are looking for but shows a way of overriding in which you may be able to adjust to work with your needs.

Comment: Thanks. How would I get my Resources.resx file to use my inherited ResourceManager class instead of System.Resources.ResourceManager?